# Secure database in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I created databse named `GSCADB` in mongodb **version 4.2.0**, I want to allow access to this database with username and password only.

I tried to follow [Enable Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/).

For now there are two users:

```
> show users
{
        "_id" : "GSCADB.codey",
        "userId" : UUID("e010fed4-382d-4bb5-8687-71eb8516b01b"),
        "user" : "codey",
        "db" : "GSCADB",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "GSCADB"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : "GSCADB.user1",
        "userId" : UUID("c6d3de16-bbac-4cee-9bb9-99d1bc9cafeb"),
        "user" : "user1",
        "db" : "GSCADB",
        "roles" : [ ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
}
```

but now I'm able to access the data withot username and password, like:

```
C:\>cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("508b0faa-8e47-43a4-8552-0ad54570a13c") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.0
Server has startup warnings:
2019-09-08T15:30:29.337+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-09-08T15:30:29.337+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-09-08T15:30:29.337+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-09-08T15:30:29.337+0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]

> show dbs
GSCADB  0.000GB
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
> use GSCADB
switched to db GSCADB
> show collections
GSCALogs
> db.GSCALogs.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d6fade919038b3530015c30"), "SHA-256" : "67072c7ccfbc0797aad8614b6d089b323b50da0e6552345431d75fdd1b9864db", "New File SHA-256" : "", "File Name" : "eicar.vbs", "File Name (GUID)" : "3297F0F2-35D3-4231-919D-1CFCF4035975", "New File Name" : "eicar.vbs", "File Size (Bytes)" : "915", "Result" : "Drop", "File type" : "vbs", "True File type" : "", "Start Job Date" : "20190904152759" }
```

Comment: Have added the security parameters in your mongod config file? If yes, please post the copy of your config file to validate

Comment: @Anban Inside `mongod.cfg` file the security line looks loke: `#security:`, i.e empty

Comment: Thats the issue. You must enable the security parameters and also the authentication mechanism. I'll post it as answer with where I can format it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the security parameters in you mongod.conf file:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled

setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: SCRAM-SHA-1
```

Comment: A hacker can simply remove those parameters from the config file and then to access all data?

Comment: If you're concerned about sql injection attacks, disable javascript in the config file under setParameter.    javascriptEnabled: false

Comment: You need to restrict the permission to the file config file and you must keep the access to your server secure through some sort of authentication mechanism.